# Print data with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following code snippet from my app:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editmode: false,
      difficulties: {},
      form: new Form({
        id: "",
        name:"",
        difficulty_id: ""
      })
    };
  },
  created(){
        axios
        .get("api/difficulty-level")
        .then(({ data }) => (this.difficulties = data));
  }
 };
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" v-model="form.difficulty_id">
    <option value disabled hidden>Difficulty</option>
    <option :value="difficulty.id" v-for="difficulty in difficulties" :key="difficulty.id">{{difficulty.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <has-error :form="form" field="difficulty_id"></has-error>
</div>
```

Here I'm trying to print the data in select option with `v-for`. But the above code gives blank output in select option:

[image]

The route exists and works.

The same axios get method is used in route:

```
{
    path: "/difficulty-level",
    component: require("./components/product/Difficulty.vue")
},
```

and the following snippet to print the data

```
<tr v-for="difficulty in difficulties" :key="difficulty.id">
  <td>{{difficulty.id}}</td>
  <td>{{difficulty.name}}</td>
  <td>
    <button @click="editModal(difficulty)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>

    <button @click="deleteUser(difficulty.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But this time I'm using axios get method in:

```
{
    path: "/tour/create",
    component: require("./components/product/Create.vue"),
},
```

Can anyone help me out figure out why my code is not working this time ?

Answer (score 0):

Got solution:

```
        axios
    .get("/api/difficulty-level")
    .then(({ data }) => (this.difficulties = data));
```

Need to add `/` before before route link for nested routes